# C: remove the front node from a doubly-linked queue

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm having some trouble conceptualizing how to remove the front node from a doubly-linked queue. I added some other pieces of my code that should give you some background to what I'm working with. I've got a little bit of stuff down for the remove_queue function, but I'm not sure if it's even right or how to finish it.

```
struct Queue {
    int size;
    struct QueueNode *dummy_head_node_ptr;
};

struct QueueNode {
    int value;
    struct QueueNode *prev_node_ptr;
    struct QueueNode *next_node_ptr;
};

void init_queue(struct Queue *queue_ptr) {
    struct QueueNode *node_ptr;

    // Create a dummy node and make it to point to itself
    node_ptr = (struct QueueNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct QueueNode));
    node_ptr->prev_node_ptr = node_ptr;
    node_ptr->next_node_ptr = node_ptr;

    // Set the queue struct to have a size of zero and
    // point to the dummy node
    queue_ptr->size = 0;
    queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr = node_ptr;
}
void insert_queue(int value, struct Queue *queue_ptr)
{
    struct QueueNode *new_node_ptr;
    new_node_ptr = (struct QueueNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct QueueNode));

    new_node_ptr->next_node_ptr = queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr;
    new_node_ptr->prev_node_ptr = queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr->prev_node_ptr;
    queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr->prev_node_ptr->next_node_ptr = new_node_ptr;
    queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr->prev_node_ptr = new_node_ptr;

    new_node_ptr->value = value;
    queue_ptr->size++;
}
int remove_queue(struct Queue *queue_ptr)
{
    assert(queue_ptr->size > 0);

    queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr->prev_node_ptr->next_node_ptr = queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr->prev_node_ptr;
    queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr->prev_node_ptr = NULL;

    queue_ptr->size = queue_ptr->size - 1;
    return queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr->next_node_ptr->value;    
}
```

Comment: If you want to understand what your code is doing (which seems necessary, given your statement of not even being sure if it is right), I suggest you draw your data on paper -- boxes for nodes, and lines/arrows for pointers. Then mentally step through your code and adjust the drawing as appropriate. If you have a whiteboard, that might make it easier.

Comment: I know what my code does, and have been using visuals. It's just the remove_queue that is giving me trouble.

Comment: Unless `remove_queue()` is not part of your code, my statement stands. There is no substitute for using the same visuals on this function so that you can truly understand it. Unless you can describe a concrete problem ("i don't know if it works" is not a concrete problem), there's really nothing for stack overflow to help with.

Comment: I've been doing that haha.

Comment: So in your visual erase the item you wish to remove from your queue. Which pointers are left hanging?

Comment: Then you have most probably also thought about free()ing all the malloc()ed memory?

Comment: Your code would be easier to follow with the dummy node assigned to a temp variable.  `QueueNode dummy = queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remember the head node. Put succesoor of the head node in place of head node. Remeber the member `value` of head node and `free` head node.

```
int remove_queue(struct Queue *queue_ptr)
{
    assert(queue_ptr->size > 0);
    if ( size == 0 )
        return queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr->value;

    struct QueueNode *firstNode = queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr->nextNode;
    int value = firstNode->value;       // remember value of first node
    queue_ptr->size--;                  // decrement number of nodes

    struct QueueNode *nextNode  = firstNode->next_node_ptr;

    queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr = nextNode;                // new head is successor of head node
    nextNode->prev_node_ptr = queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr; // predecessor of new head node is queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr
                                                              // if queue_ptr->size == 0 then nextNode == queue_ptr->dummy_head_node_ptr

    free( firstNode  );                                       // free first node
    return value;   
}
```

Comment: He has a dummy head. So as I understood the dummy head shall not be deleted. His code shall be entirely rewritten. So your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: This gets me moving in the right direction. Thank you, @Rabbid76.

Comment: you must assert first that `queue_ptr` is not `NULL` before you do anything. That's because `queue_ptr->size` would give you `segmentation fault` in-case `queue_ptr == NULL`!

Answer (score 2):

```
... -->[tail]<--->[dummy_head_node_ptr node]<--->[head]<--->[2nd node]<-- ...
                            ^
                            |
                   queue.dummy_head_node_ptr
```

Using a diagram helps you clarify what you need to do. Lets try to remove the [head] node. We know that we need to set dummy_head_node_ptr's next to be [2nd node] and [2nd node]'s prev to be [dummy_head_node_ptr node].

So in this case we just want dummy_head_node_ptr->next_node_ptr to be what head's next_node_ptr points to. We can do that with

```
dummy_head_node_ptr->next_node_ptr = dummy_head_node_ptr->next_node_ptr->next_node_ptr;
```

But, its bad practice to have leaky memory, so lets not forget to free the head node.

So save dummy_head_node_ptr->next_node_ptr into a temporary variable. Then free it at the end.